# Define approvals in yaml release pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on release pipelines and looking into any mechanism to define release approval flows in Yaml. I checked the Rest API too and could not find any pointers.

I am looking into a approval process where a deployment to an environment would need approval with a timeout setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** In sprint 155 (7/30) Microsoft released approvals for YAML pipelines that use Environments:

[image]

The pipeline run deploying to the environment will stop for approval at the start of the stage:

[image]

---

**First answer:**

This feature not exist yet in the YAML (multi stage) pipelines.

The feature is on [the road map](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-roadmap-update-for-2019-q2/) and planned to be in Q2 but the [work item](https://dev.azure.com/mseng/AzureDevOpsRoadmap/_workitems/edit/1510336) state still "In Progress".

It's really useful and basic release process and I hope it will be available soon.

Comment: manual approvals (called 'checks') [now exist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/checks?view=azure-devops) - I have tested them on a multi-stage pipeline and it's working

Comment: @alv this is exactly what I wrote in the beginning of my answer :)

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't read fully my bad, but hey that's a link to the proper docs at least!

Comment: Is there some workaround to work with approvals in YAML script?? , for example Enviroments, Git Repo triggers or Splitting YAML files ? ,another options ?